# MUI TableCell custom style not overriding width prop

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm creating a custom table to show only 3/5 columns on mobile as well as for the tablecell to fit the cell content. I've gotten the columns to disappear but for some reason, the css prop I added isn't working and the default table follows some sort of width heirarchy where the first data column is the widest, second is less wide, third is smaller etc.

The following is what I have, but it's working as expected (the width is far wider than the actual data the cell displays).

```
const CustomCell = styled(TableCell)(({theme}) => ({
  color: 'white',
  padding: 0,
  "&.MuiTableCell-sizeMedium": {
    width: 'fit-content'
  },
  "& .MuiTableSortLabel-root": {
    color: theme.palette.primary.main,
    "& .MuiSvgIcon-root": {
      color: theme.palette.primary.main
    }
  },
}))
```

I haven't touched the default table Mui provides so I won't include it because it's absurdly long but here's the table component itself (maybe how I render the cells might be of use):

```
return (
    <Box sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
      <Paper
        sx={{
          width: "100%",
          mg: 2,
          background: "rgba(255,255,255,0.05)",
          backdropFilter: "blur(5px)",
          WebkitBackdropFilter: "blur(5px)",

        }}
      >
        <EnhancedTableToolbar numSelected={selected.length} />
        <TableContainer>
          <Table
            sx={{ minWidth: 750 }}
            aria-labelledby="tableTitle"
            size={dense ? "small" : "medium"}
          >
            <EnhancedTableHead
              numSelected={selected.length}
              order={order}
              orderBy={orderBy}
              onSelectAllClick={handleSelectAllClick}
              onRequestSort={handleRequestSort}
              rowCount={expenses.length}
            />
            <TableBody>
              {visibleRows.map((row, index) => {
                const isItemSelected = isSelected(row.id);
                const labelId = `enhanced-table-checkbox-${index}`;

                return (
                  <TableRow
                    hover
                    onClick={(event) => handleClick(event, row.id)}
                    role="checkbox"
                    aria-checked={isItemSelected}
                    tabIndex={-1}
                    key={row.id}
                    selected={isItemSelected}
                    sx={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                  >
                    <CustomCell padding="checkbox">
                      <Checkbox
                        sx={{
                          ...{ color: (theme) => theme.palette.primary.main },
                        }}
                        color="primary"
                        checked={isItemSelected}
                        inputProps={{
                          "aria-labelledby": labelId,
                        }}
                      />
                    </CustomCell>
                    {Object.entries(row).map(([key,value]) => {
                      if ((key === 'id' || key === 'category') && !isAboveMediumScreen) {
                        return;
                      } else if (key === 'date') {
                        return (

                          <CustomCell size="small">{dayjs(value).format('DD-MM-YYYY')}</CustomCell>
                        )
                      } else if (key === 'price') {
                        return (

                          <CustomCell>${value}</CustomCell>
                        )

                      } else {
                        return (

                          <CustomCell>{value}</CustomCell>
                        )
                      }
                    })}
                  </TableRow>
                );
              })}
              {emptyRows > 0 && (
                <TableRow
                  style={{
                    height: (dense ? 33 : 53) * emptyRows,
                  }}
                >
                  <CustomCell colSpan={6} />
                </TableRow>
              )}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
        <TablePagination
          rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25]}
          component="div"
          count={expenses.length}
          rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
          page={page}
          onPageChange={handleChangePage}
          onRowsPerPageChange={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
        />
      </Paper>
      <FormControlLabel
        control={<Switch checked={dense} onChange={handleChangeDense} />}
        label="Dense padding"
      />
    </Box>
  );
```